Strapi - Multiple plugins development
I have strapi project with several custom type-script strapi plugins.
When I want to make a change on some plugin I have to make sure there's a yarn develop command running from the plugin folder that will compile the ts to the plugin dist folder.
If I am developing my project with 3 custom plugins It means that i I'll have to make sure that besides the strapi root run of yarn develop there will be running another 3 NodeJS processes - 1 per custom plugin.
Do I miss something and is there a better way like 1 command for all that will listen and compile code for a project all of my custom plugins?
